# Terraform, creating a CloudFront distributon reusable module with and without multiples Origins

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, terraform, siteorigin

I have an application that needs CloudFront + s3. I want to create a CloudFront module and make it reusable for others applications.

My problem is that I have one application that needs two Origins ( s3_origin_config and a custom_origin_config) AND other application that needs ONLY s3_origin_config.

The question is: How can I have a module that handles application that needs two Origins and another that needs only one Origin.

Below an example of my code:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "${var.app_name}-${var.environment}"
    origin_path = "/${var.environment}/${var.setup}/public"
    s3_origin_config {
       origin_access_identity = ${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
       }
  }


#HERE, I would like something like if $second_origin, then:
#I know there is no if in terraform, just to have an example ;)
origin {             
   domain_name = "${var.second_origin_domain_name}"
   origin_id   = "Custom-${var.second_origin_domain_name}"
   custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
  custom_header {
    name  = "${var.second_origin_header_name}"
    value = "${var.second_origin_header_key}"
  }
}...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two cloudfront resources with different origin requirements. Using `count`, you can enable one resource and disable another resource at same time. This will allow you to use same module for different origin requirements.

Here is simple example.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_app1" {
  count = "${var.something ? 1 : 0}"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_app2" {
  count = "${var.something ? 0 : 1}"
}
```